# Should I fclose(file) if an error occured?

Tags: c, file, file-io, fopen, fclose

## Code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (!fp)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open a file\n");
    // fclose(fp) <-- should I close file here?
    exit(1);
}
// Some operations on the file.
fclose(fp);
```

## Question:

If `fopen()` fails to open a file, should I still call `fclose()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `fclose()` inside `if` block. Once `fopen()` fails, it retruns NULL which need not be *closed*.

To elaborate, if `fopen()` is success, it will return a `FILE *`. That needs to be closed. FWIW, the returned pointer in this case, be of whatever *value*, gurantees to compare unequal with a NULL. In other words, if `fopen()` is a success, the returned pointer will always *FAIL* the `if(!fp)` check.

In error scenario (when the file cannot be opned for *some* reason), NULL will be retrurned. A NULL return value means, the file was **not** opened. You don't close what is not already opened. Simple.

Comment: I knew that `fopen()` returns NULL but I wasn't sure if file was opened or not. Thanks!

Comment: I would say even clearer: since on error null is returned, you have nothing to close.

Comment: A hanging issue: is it OK to call `fclose(NULL)`?  I think it is, yet see no spec to back up.  (Note:2 "retrun"s in answer)

Comment: I've just tested `fclose(NULL)`. Nothing special happened.